# Call SQL procedure from x++ in AX Dynamics 365

Tags: sql-server, x++, dynamics-365

I have successfully called sql procedure in x++ class (ax dynamics 365) with params, but unable to get return/output value in x++ class from sql procedure.
Here is the following code:

**X++ code:**

```
Connection connection = new Connection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
str sql;
ResultSet result; 
SqlStatementExecutePermission permission;
int64 value1 = 8;
str value2 = "War-001";
sql = strFmt('Exec [UpdateTimesheetRecord] \'%1\',\'%2\'', value1 ,  value2 ); 
permission = new SqlStatementExecutePermission(sql);
permission.assert();
try
{
    result = statement.executeQuery(sql); 
}
catch
{ 
}
CodeAccessPermission::revertAssert();
```

**Sql procedure:**

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE UpdateTimesheetRecord
@Value1 INT,
@Value2 VARCHAR(50)
AS
Begin Transaction 
UPDATE  WARHCMTIMESHEET
SET [STATUS] = @Value1  
Where TimesheetId = @Value2 
If @@ERROR <> 0 
    Begin
        RollBack Transaction 
        Return -1 
    End
Else
    Begin
        Commit Transaction
        Return @Value1
    End 
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is working to get resultset from sql procedure, if you are using select query in sql procedure but if you update a record in sql procedure and want to get return value in x++ it won't works:

```
Connection connection = new Connection();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement(); 
ResultSet result; str sql; int output; ResultSet testRS;
SqlStatementExecutePermission permission; 
sql = strFmt('Exec [GetAllTimesheet]'); 
permission = new SqlStatementExecutePermission(sql);
permission.assert();  
testRS = statement.executeQuery(sql);
while(testRS.next())
    {
        info(testRS.getString(2));
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unless this is a valid answer to your question, you should remove this reply and add it to your question instead by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67968586/edit). Answering your own question is allowed, but this removes it from the "unanswered questions" list. If you indeed wanted to answer your own question, then you should also accept your own answer.